# Picasso is loading image including transparent portion of image

Tags: android, picasso

I want to set image only in the first layer(non-transparent) of below image whereas below two layers are transparent.

Picasso is loading an image in full image including transparent area.

[image]

Comment: what is the format of the image?

Comment: @RahulChandrabhan .png

Comment: i have same issue ?